# Comparing key from 2 or more dictionaries based on keyword and showing values in rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, cryptography

I have two dictionaries parsed from urls apis for crypto rates as below:

dict1

```
{'INR-BTC': {'Bid': '893201.4', 'Ask': '908286.6', 'LT Rate': '902553.6', 'LT Vol': '0.003604'}, 'INR-ETH': {'Bid': '30927', 'Ask': '32136', 'LT Rate': '31527.6', 'LT Vol': '2.752963'}, 'INR-XRP': {'Bid': '21.06', 'Ask': '21.79', 'LT Rate': '21.79', 'LT Vol': '50'}, 'INR-USDT': {'Bid': '77.5', 'Ask': '79.5', 'LT Rate': '76.5', 'LT Vol': '15.57'}, 'INR-BCH': {'Bid': '20709', 'Ask': '21325.2', 'LT Rate': '21005.4', 'LT Vol': '0.128696'}, 'INR-LTC': {'Bid': '4368', 'Ask': '4656.6', 'LT Rate': '4500.6', 'LT Vol': '6.7579'}, 'INR-XMR': {'Bid': '7152.6', 'Ask': '7566', 'LT Rate': '7378.8', 'LT Vol': '1.40361'}, 'INR-BUC': {'Bid': '3.1', 'Ask': '6', 'LT Rate': '5', 'LT Vol': '10000'}, 'INR-NEO': {'Bid': '1654.38', 'Ask': '1712.88', 'LT Rate': '1698.06', 'LT Vol': '15.599066'}, 'INR-DASH': {'Bid': '2300', 'Ask': '17000', 'LT Rate': '0', 'LT Vol': '0'}, 'INR-XDC': {'Bid': '0.5', 'Ask': '0.6', 'LT Rate': '0.5', 'LT Vol': '0'}, 'INR-TRX': {'Bid': '2.0358', 'Ask': '2.1372', 'LT Rate': '2.0748', 'LT Vol': '10411.99'}, 'INR-SOLVE': {'Bid': '0', 'Ask': '0', 'LT Rate': '0', 'LT Vol': '0'}}
```

dict2

```
{'btcinr': {'Bid': '882970.0', 'Ask': '886400.0', 'LT Rate': '886400.0', 'LT Vol': '81.1214'}, 'xrpinr': {'Bid': '21.0', 'Ask': '21.1', 'LT Rate': '21.0436', 'LT Vol': '207631.0'}, 'ethinr': {'Bid': '30900.9', 'Ask': '30938.0', 'LT Rate': '30938.0', 'LT Vol': '674.309'}, 'trxinr': {'Bid': '2.04', 'Ask': '2.045', 'LT Rate': '2.045', 'LT Vol': '9122716.0'}, 'zilinr': {'Bid': '0.0', 'Ask': '0.0', 'LT Rate': '0.26', 'LT Vol': '0.0'}, 'batinr': {'Bid': '27.058', 'Ask': '27.441', 'LT Rate': '27.154', 'LT Vol': '84890.92'}, 'usdtinr': {'Bid': '76.47', 'Ask': '76.48', 'LT Rate': '76.47', 'LT Vol': '640158.59'}, 'wrxinr': {'Bid': '10.4', 'Ask': '10.42', 'LT Rate': '10.4', 'LT Vol': '1238004.0'}, 'maticinr': {'Bid': '2.123', 'Ask': '2.149', 'LT Rate': '2.149', 'LT Vol': '992234.0'}, 'bchabcinr': {'Bid': '20590.0', 'Ask': '20932.0', 'LT Rate': '20932.0', 'LT Vol': '20.901'}, 'bnbinr': {'Bid': '1756.29', 'Ask': '1771.77', 'LT Rate': '1756.29', 'LT Vol': '201.05'}, 'bttinr': {'Bid': '0.03431', 'Ask': '0.0345', 'LT Rate': '0.0345', 'LT Vol': '93008934.0'}, 'chzinr': {'Bid': '0.0', 'Ask': '0.0', 'LT Rate': '0.0', 'LT Vol': '0.0'}, 'oneinr': {'Bid': '0.0', 'Ask': '0.0', 'LT Rate': '0.0', 'LT Vol': '0.0'}, 'ltcinr': {'Bid': '4435.53', 'Ask': '4457.0', 'LT Rate': '4457.0', 'LT Vol': '460.084'}}
```

As you can see each dict has a key which is a cryptomarket name and a nested dict with the values for 'bid', 'ask' etc.
However the cryptomarket names are different in both the dict but they can be parsed using just the crypto name like btc.
(eg. dict1 has 'INR-BTC' as key and dict2 has 'btcinr' as key)

I want to display data from both dicts in the following format:
[image: data in columns]

Even though the keys are different, I can search for just BTC and extract from each list as follows:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
if 'BTC' in key:
    print(key,value)
```

It will be tedious searching for each crypto by name in both dicts as above. Any better way to do this?
Also, I cannot figure out how to get it into the table format as shown.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you basically wants a dataframe constructed from `dict1` and `dict2` with multiindex columns?

Comment: Not sure what that does. Can you guide me? Thanks

Comment: Do you require `pandas` based solution? just wanted to make sure as you tagged it with `pandas`..

Comment: Any solution is fine. :)

Comment: So what will be the output in case `dict1` contains `Bid` and `Ask` for some currency pair but `dict2` doesn't contain that pair? Is `NaN` will be fine in such case?

Comment: Yup. NaN is absolutely fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to create a new dataframe from `dict` then use `.loc` to select the `Bid` and `Ask` rows, then use `Index.str` methods to normalize the columns in both datframes(so that columns in both dataframes match), finally use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [`DatFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict1).loc[['Bid', 'Ask']]
d1.columns = d1.columns.str.split('-').str[-1].str.upper()

d2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict2).loc[['Bid', 'Ask']]
d2.columns = d2.columns.str.extract(r'(\w+)inr', expand=False).str.upper()

df = pd.concat([d1, d2], keys=('dict1', 'dict2')).unstack()
```

Result:

```
print(df)
         BCH                BTC            BUC       DASH             ETH               LTC              NEO          SOLVE          TRX           USDT         XDC          XMR          XRP            BAT           BCHABC               BNB               BTT          CHZ       MATIC         ONE        WRX         ZIL     
         Bid      Ask       Bid       Ask  Bid  Ask   Bid    Ask      Bid      Ask      Bid     Ask      Bid      Ask   Bid  Ask     Bid     Ask    Bid    Ask  Bid  Ask     Bid   Ask    Bid    Ask     Bid     Ask      Bid      Ask      Bid      Ask      Bid     Ask  Bid  Ask    Bid    Ask  Bid  Ask   Bid    Ask  Bid  Ask
dict1  20709  21325.2  893201.4  908286.6  3.1    6  2300  17000    30927    32136     4368  4656.6  1654.38  1712.88     0    0  2.0358  2.1372   77.5   79.5  0.5  0.6  7152.6  7566  21.06  21.79     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
dict2    NaN      NaN  882970.0  886400.0  NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  30900.9  30938.0  4435.53  4457.0      NaN      NaN   NaN  NaN    2.04   2.045  76.47  76.48  NaN  NaN     NaN   NaN   21.0   21.1  27.058  27.441  20590.0  20932.0  1756.29  1771.77  0.03431  0.0345  0.0  0.0  2.123  2.149  0.0  0.0  10.4  10.42  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Shubham thank you! That worked well. Can I choose just to include a few crypto like ETH, BTC, XRP, USDT?  I have zero knowledge of pandas

Comment: sure you can do that,  simply use `df[['ETH', 'BTC', 'XRP', 'USDT']]`

Comment: You are amazing! :)

Comment: I added another dataframe with the belowd5 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(coindcx).loc[['Bid', 'Ask']]
d5.columns = d5.columns.str.extract(r'(\w+)INR', expand=False).str.upper()

It gives following data:
ADA            BNB              BTC            BTC         CHR  \
Bid  9.27000000  1894.55000000  890576.00000000  890090.432388  4.52000000   
Ask  9.34000000  1912.11000000  892211.99000000  896068.942148  4.60000000

Comment: I added to the df  with the following:
df = pd.concat([d1, d2,d3,d4,d5], keys=('buyu', 'wazir','bitbns','unocoin','coindcx')).unstack()

This is generating error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    386         # no blocks that would get missing values (can lead to type upcasts)
    387         # unless we're an extension dtype.
--> 388         all(not ju.is_na or ju.block.is_extension for ju in join_units)
    389         and
    390         # no blocks with indexers (as then the dimensions do not fit)

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'

all the other dataframes are working fine.

Comment: @Vinay Lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219265/data-science-discussions-5)